# for loop pair iteration will not display all pairs(without repetition). I only get the first two values of list - python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I'm not able to display all of the pair iterations(ex: query params: 321,212,341)

```
[321][212] = 0.564
[321][341] = 0.26
[212][341] = 0.22
```

and I'm not sure if that has to do with the for loop:

```
sim_pairs = []
match_pair = {}

for i in range(len(matID) - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(matID) - 1):
        mat1 = int(matID[i])
        mat2 = int(matID[i + 1])
        compute_similarity = similarity_material(mat1, mat2, method='matching')
        s = compute_similarity
        current_item, next_item = matID[i], matID[i + 1]
        sim_pairs.append((current_item, next_item, s))
        sim_pairs = sorted(sim_pairs, key=(lambda x: x[1]), reverse=True)
        return return_object(sim_pairs)
```

If anyone can help me understand why the pairings/calculations won't display would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: You never use `j`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never use your j counter, so you're comparing adjacent values a bunch of times in the inner loop, but those values never change.

You might as well set mat1 outside of the inner loop, like this:

```
    sim_pairs = []
    match_pair = {}

    for i in range(len(matID) - 1):
        mat1 = int(matID[i])

        for j in range(i+1, len(matID) - 1):
            mat2 = int(matID[j])
            compute_similarity = similarity_material(mat1, mat2, method='matching')
            s = compute_similarity
            current_item, next_item = matID[i], matID[j + 1]
            sim_pairs.append((current_item, next_item, s))
            sim_pairs = sorted(sim_pairs, key=(lambda x: x[1]), reverse=True)
    return return_object(sim_pairs)
```

I'm not sure if that is the whole solution, but hopefully this helps you identify an error.

Comment: this actually helped me figure out the problem and also identify some other minuscule errors, thanks for helping a newbie out!

Answer (score 0):

You're never using the indexes from the inner loop.

You're ending the inner loop too early. You'll never reach the last element.

You have the `return` statement inside the loop, so the loop never repeats.

Also, it's generally easier to write and read loops if you iterate over the list elements, not the indexes. You can use `enumerate()` if you need both.

```
for i, mat1 in enumerate(matID[:-1]):
    for mat2 in matID[i+1:]:
        compute_similarity = similarity_material(mat1, mat2, method='matching')
        s = compute_similarity
        sim_pairs.append((mat1, mat2, s))
        sim_pairs = sorted(sim_pairs, key=(lambda x: x[1]), reverse=True)
    return return_object(sim_pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for all the combinations of three things taken 2 at a time, then for gosh sakes use the Python module that is intended for that:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations((321,212,341),2))
[(321, 212), (321, 341), (212, 341)]
>>>
```